# polymer paper-scroll-header-panel sticky footer

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to get a sticky footer with polymer, using something similar to this: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/ The problem I'm running into is that the mainContainer div is not a flex column container.

Comment: Hey! Could you please provide an example (e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I believe that that is for an outdated version of polymer. To make a sticky footer you should just make the parent `layout-vertical` and then the main content `flex`